# SpringMVC:"Cannot find declaration to go to"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I can't understand why does it give an error.Please,help me!!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Spring isn't aware of your custom ViewResolver. You should denote it with `@Bean` annotation

Comment: I added @bean and started tomcat,the same as in the picture webpage with HTTP Status 404((

Answer (score 0):

You've got

> WEB-INF/view

in your folder structure and

> WEB-INF/views

in your ViewResolver (which does need the `@Bean` annotation as Nikolay stated) which is why you are receiving a 404.

Comment: I have corrected,but it doesn't work-the same as in the picture webpage with HTTP Status 404(((